# Can I set the speed of .slideUp as a variable?

Tags: jquery

I have created a jsFiddle of a cursor trail, which slowly fades out. However, I would like the user to be able to enter a speed that this will fade out. They will enter a speed, click "Go", and they cursor trail will disappear at that speed.

I have created a variable that stores the value entered, but I don't know how I can take this number and use it as the duration. Could someone please take a look and help me out?

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w50x3L2a/1/**

---

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.go').click(function () {
        speedvar = $('.speed').val();
        
        $('.mousearea').mousemove(function (e) {
            pointer = $('<img>').attr({'src': 'http://www.bangkokpost.com/common/img/icons/icon-dotBlue.png'});
            $(document.body).append(pointer);
            
            pointer.css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                top: e.pageY + 2,
                left: e.pageX + 2
            }).slideUp(speedvar);
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.mousearea {
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  margin:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p style="display:inline; margin-right:20px;">Fade Out Speed</p>

<input class="speed" type="text"></input>
<button class="go">Go</button>

<div class="mousearea"></div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: little sidenote: instead of `.attr({'src': 'http://www.ba...'});`, you can use `.attr('src','http://www.ba...');` ...A little cleaner I think and maybe even faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.slideUp`](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/#slideUp-duration-complete) excepts a `Number` a parameter but `.val()` is returning a `String` in that case.

You need to convert `speedvar` to number using [`parseInt(string, radix)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```
speedvar = parseInt($('.speed').val(), 10);
```

> The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be supplied [...] If any other string is supplied, or if the duration parameter is omitted, the default duration of  400 milliseconds is used.

Comment: well, not entirely true, as `slow` can be used too... ;)

Comment: @webeno oh yes, forgot that :D

Comment: That has done the job, thank you for the quick response!

Comment: @user3623348 An additional note: take care with your `$('.mousearea').mousemove` as you would register an **additional** `mousemove` with every click. And your `speedvar` and `pointer` are in the global scope, which should be avoided.